# How to add SignalR connection to Hub group from outside the Hub?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Before starting, I want to mention that this is not exactly a duplicate, the other similar questions do not have any useful answers for my case.

In my ASP.Net Core 2.1, I have an action which can be called using AJAX (its name is `CreateConversation`).

In this application, I have an active SignalR connection for every user on my application (so the connection starts when the user refreshes/navigates the page).

When this action is called using AJAX (the user clicked on some button on the page), I want to add that connection to a specific group of my `Hub`. The problem here, to be able to add the connection to a hub group from the controller, I need access to the Id of that connection from HubCallerContext), and this Id is not available outside the hub.

```
public class ConversationsController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateConversation()
    {
        // How can this be made possible?
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(/**Context.ConnectionId**/, "SomeGroup");
    }
}
```

Untill now, I have never presisted the Id of my hub connections manually (I haven't needed that yet). Is persisting the HubCalledContext.Id a must to be able to solve this issue? or is there any better approach in solving this? I was thinking about persisting it in the sessions for example, but I have no access to the HttpContext in SignalR. I appreciate any optimal suggesion to be able to add my connection to the required hub group from outside the hub itself.

Comment: You can access the `HttpContext` via the `Hub.Context` property. `var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();`. You can try and add cookies etc. to the response but when I tried it I couldn't get the client to find the cookie (but you might do better :-) )

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand you want to add a connection Id to any group in a controller

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            // Inject to Hub
            services.AddScoped<ChatHub>();
}
```

hub class

```
public class Chathub : hub
{
    IHubContext<Chathub> _hubcontext;
    public ChatHub(IHubContext<Chathub> hubcontext)
    {
        _hubcontext = hubcontext;
    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
}
```

controller

```
public class AnyController 
{
        //if you want to access connectionId in here , add hubcontext in here too
    private readonly ChatHub _chatHub;
    public AnyController(ChatHub chatHub)
    {
        _chatHub = chatHub;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _chatHub.AddToGroup("groupname");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem with this approach is that my Hub depends on that service, so using DI throws circular dependency exception

Comment: I have the feeling that I am doing something wrong in the design. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: Hi @Mohammed, you can use dependency injection by adding IServiceProvider to your constructor instead of the service itself and then get the required service. Anyways there is always some controversy because of the ServiceLocator antipattern issue [link](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)